# Python indexing question - 'IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Please can someone tell me why the following code does not work, and what the best work arounds for this are?

```py
Choices # variable containing True or False in each element.
Choices.shape = (18978,)
BestOption # variable containing 1 or 2 in each element.
BestOption.shape = (18978, 1)

Choices[BestOption==1] # I want to look up the values in choices for all instances where BestOption is 1.
```

I get the following error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Comment: `BestOption==1` is a boolean array with the same shape as `BestOptions`.  Such array, when used as an index, has to match, in shape, either the whole array or one of its dimensions.  In other words to index a (n,) array, you need to use a (n,) boolean mask, not a (n,1).  You may need to review some numpy basics on dimensions and indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BestOption` is a 1-D "column vector" that's actually made up of many rows and is treated like a 2-D matrix. You can simply reshape it back to a 1-D "row vector":

```py
Choices[BestOption.reshape(-1)==1]
```